# Passing null to methods with Optional as parameters

Tags: java, null, option-type

```
CONTROLLER CLASS
@PostMapping("Calculate")
    public String Calculate(@ModelAttribute("currencyAndAmount") @Valid CurrencyViewModel currencyViewModel,
                            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            var entity = currencyExchange_logic.CurrencyViewModelToEntity(currencyViewModel);
            String start = Optional.ofNullable(entity.getDateFrom().toString()).orElse("");
            String end = Optional.ofNullable(entity.getDateTo().toString()).orElse("");
            try {
                var currencyJson = currencyExchange_logic.currencyJson(start, end);
                var calVal = currencyExchange_logic.calculateMoney(currencyJson, entity);
                model.addAttribute("endValue", calVal);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return "end";
        } else {
            return "formPage";
        }
    }

SERVICE CLASS

@Override
    public MonetaryAmountJson currencyJson(String start, String end) throws IOException {
        String dates = "/" + start + "/" + end;
        URL url = new URL("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/c" + dates);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder jsonObject = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonObject.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonObject), MonetaryAmountJson.class);
    }
```

The question that I have is that in the line:

```
var currencyJson = currencyExchange_logic.currencyJson(start, end);
```

So in a frontend form there are 2 date inputs that can be left empty (not filled by user)
and I want to pass to currencyJson() method Optional.of(given date (maybe null).toString()) the logic within it i.e. Optional.ofNullable(null).orElse(""); won't return "" (empty String). Am I passing "" or null to currencyJson()?

Comment: In your current code `Optional.ofNullable(entity.getDateFrom().toString())`, would definitely throw a `NullPointerException` if `entity.getDateFrom()` is `null`. You should be trying `Optional.ofNullable(entity.getDateFrom()).map(Date::toString).orElse("");`

Comment: Also please try not to include code that is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `entity.getDateFrom()` is actually null, `Optional.ofNullable(entity.getDateFrom().toString())` should throw a `NullPointerException`, because `toString` will be called on null before `Optional.ofNullable` is called.

But your question doesn't state that you get a `NullPointerException` in your original code, so think that the date values are **not** null, but rather some default value.

Now, if the default values are actually null, and if you want to continue using `Optional` you could do this instead:

```
String start = Optional.ofNullable(entity.getDateFrom())
                       .map(Object::toString)
                       .orElse("")
String end = Optional.ofNullable(entity.getDateTo())
                       .map(Object::toString)
                       .orElse("");
```

...or (easier):

```
String start = Objects.toString(entity.getDateFrom(), "")
String end = Objects.toString(entity.getDateTo(), "")
```

Comment: thanks, and toString() was throwing nullpointerxception